# Store and manage a fixed amount of things generally

Tags: java

I have an `enum` let's say with four values. Let's call them A, B, C, D.

```
public enum Categories
{
    A,
    B,
    C,
    D
}
```

I then have a `Thing` which stores something and has one of the values from my `enum`.

```
public class Thing
{
    public final Categories category;
    public int var;

    public Thing (Categories category) {
        this.category = category;
    }
}
```

All good. Now I know I will have **exactly** four things. I can change which things, I can set them to null, but I will always have one of each. I will always have **exactly** one `A`,`B`, `C` and one `D`. No more no less. So I store them in my `Container`. Like this.

```
public class Container
{
    private final Map<Categories, Thing> things = new HashMap<>();

    public Container () {
        for (int i = 0; i < Categories.values().length; i++) {
            things.put(Categories.values()[i], null);
        }
    }

    public Thing getThing (Categories c) {
        return things.get(c);
    }

    public Thing setThing (Categories c, Thing t) {
        Thing returnThing = null;

        if (things.containsKey(c) && t.category == c) {
            if (things.get (c) != null) {
                returnThing = things.get (c);
            }
            things.put(c, t);
        }

        return returnThing;
    }

    public Thing removeThing (Categories c) {
        Thing returnThing = null;

        if (things.containsKey(c) && things.get(c) != null) {
            returnThing = things.get(c);
            things.put (c, null);
        }

        return returnThing;
    }
}
```

While this code works, it feels a bit clunky. As I know I will never add another `key`, nor remove one. Is there any pattern I lack the knowledge of that solves this issue? Or, *doubt it*, is this the way to accomplish a task such as this?

I would prefer to stay away from external dependencies such as `Guava`.

Answer (score 5):

Enum names are [generally given in the singular form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15755955/naming-of-enums-in-java-singular-or-plural), rather than plural. Hence you may want to call your enum `Category`.

You should also consider using an [`EnumMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) for your `Map` implementation:

```
private final Map<Category, Thing> things = new EnumMap<>(Category.class);
```

BTW, the return value of [`Map.put()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put-K-V-) will be the previously associated value, so you don't need the inner `if (things.get (c) != null) { returnThing = things.get(c); }` parts of your code (`setThing()`/`removeThing()`).

One more observation about your `setThing()` method: Since you are doing a `t.category == c` check before the insertion, why not make the method signature just `setThing(Thing t)`? In that case, the method body simply becomes:

```
public Thing setThing (Thing t) {
    // t == null check required?
    return things.put(t.category, t);
}
```

Now, to your question... may I know what's the fixation with *exactly four* entries in your `things` object, to the extent of mapping to `null` values? There is no difference in calling `Map.get()` for a mapped-to-`null` key, and an unmapped key: both returns `null`. The only difference is in `Map.containsKey()`, but as far as I can tell your class doesn't really expose this to external callers (which I guess is a good design). Is there a more relevant larger context to show how *exactly four* entries in `things` are being depended upon?

**edit**: The code-smell I observe here is that your code is doing/stating the obvious. Consider:

- You use `null` to practically indicate the absence of a mapped `Thing`.
- `things` is pre-populated with all your enum keys, so `things.containsKey(category)` will always be `true`.

  - In other words, `things.containsKey(category) && anotherCondition` can be simplified to `anotherCondition`.
- When you are adding or removing mapped `Thing`s, you do a `null`-check to return the previous `non`-null mapping...
- ***but*** if the mapping is to `null`, you return a `null` anyways.

As mentioned above, the relevant methods in `Map` already returns the previously associated value or `null`, so your `null` checks are pretty much redundant.

Unless your code clearly distinguishes between the absence of a mapping and a `null`-mapping, which I don't see here, you should simplify your logic to treat both as the same. If you do however, then the difference for `Map.containsKey()` becomes crucial here, and then all the more should you *not* have `null`-mappings...

Comment: It is used in a very larger project that I am working. Posting it all and in its context would require somewhere around a million worth of bounty...

Comment: @Emz wells not to share all the context, but perhaps the parts where, for some reason, shows why they require `things` to have exactly four entries *while* they seem to work reasonably well with `null` values? That's the part which I don't quite get...

Comment: Think a car, one of the `things` is the engine, another the wheels etc. Where `null` means it has none.

Comment: Then it's not exactly five, no more, no less isn't it? More like, at most five?

Comment: (In this simplified example) a car consists of exterior, wheels, engine and a exhaust pipe. Now if one were to steal one of them (or while they are being replaced) I accept `null` as saying "the part is missing".

Comment: @Emz any parts of your code require knowing whether the engine of car *exists in the first place*? If not, then whether `things` contains a mapping for the engine, or has the engine mapped to `null` becomes immaterial as `things.get()` returning `null` will always mean "the part is missing".

Comment: There are many parts of the code that requires to know if a thing exists or not. The thing I want to avoid is confusion "why can't I add a spoiler?", because these cars do not have spoilers in this project. I will never add spoilers for it. It wouldn't make any sense to add spoiler for one car. Instead, if I want to add spoilers I will add a new `Category`.

Comment: @Emz right, so if there's a `Category.E` value now, your `Container` will also automagically get a new mapping `Category.E => null`. For all intent and purposes, `Category.E` is "missing". If you don't add the mapping for `Category.E`, it is still the same as "missing".

Answer (score 0):

How about just use a EnumMap initialized with full population.

```
Map<Categories, Thing> storage = Arrays.asList(Categories.values())
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
         (c) -> c, 
         (c) -> new Thing(c), 
         (c, c) -> throw new UnsupportedOperationException(), 
         () -> new EnumMap<Categories, Thing>(Categories.class) ));
```

This way works almost exactly the same as your class. And it conforms to java Collection library. And it does not allow adding new element, since there is just so much value for the Enum. And it works with null.

Comment: I will dig into that latter, see what I discover.